# AlamofireSource doesn't load images

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3

I want to load my image by using `AlamofireSource`.

```
var images = [InputSource]()
for img in arr_imgs
            {
                if(img != "")
                {

                    var mimg = img.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\", with: "/", options: .literal, range: nil)
                    print("==> \(mimg)")
                    if let alamofireSource = AlamofireSource(urlString: mimg)
 {
    images.append(alamofireSource)
                    }
                    else {
                       print("it doesnt work")
                    }

                }

            }
```

the console log:

```
==> http://kashanmap.ir/media/k2/galleries/6881/1.jpg 
it doesnt work
==> http://kashanmap.ir/media/k2/galleries/6881/2.jpg 
it doesnt work
==> http://kashanmap.ir/media/k2/galleries/6881/3.jpg 
it doesnt work
==> http://kashanmap.ir/media/k2/galleries/6881/4.jpg 
it doesnt work
==> http://kashanmap.ir/media/k2/galleries/6881/5.jpg 
it doesn't work
```

why `AlomofireSource` doesn't work?

Comment: how you declared images?

Comment: the url's comes from server.

Comment: images.append(alamofireSource) In this how you declared images?

Comment: updated my question. `var images = [InputSource]()`

Comment: try this   if let alamofireSource = AlamofireSource(urlString: mimg  as String)!

Comment: I got the same error.

Comment: Have you tried with https urls?